# Extract URL from body of email

Tags: excel, vba, outlook

I have data to add to Excel. I found that we can do that by Outlook VBA. The content comes in the following format:

Title: Undergraduate student

Gender: Male

Country: Albania

Keyword:
1.Environment
2. Population

First Name: John

Phone number: 0532432444

Username: test@dda.com

File upload: http://all-free-download.com/free-photos/download/autumns-evening-sun_513398.html

---

I followed an old article and created this code:

```vb
Sub CopyToExcel()
    Dim xlApp As Object
    Dim xlWB As Object
    Dim xlSheet As Object

    Dim olItem As Outlook.MailItem
    Dim vText As Variant
    Dim sText As String
    Dim vItem As Variant

    Dim i As Long
    Dim rCount As Long
    Dim bXStarted As Boolean

    Const strPath As String = "E:\Project\Test oulook.xlsx"   ' the path of the workbook

    If Application.ActiveExplorer.Selection.Count = 0 Then
        MsgBox "No Items selected!", vbCritical, "Error"
        Exit Sub
    End If

    On Error Resume Next

    Set xlApp = GetObject(, "Excel.Application")
    If Err <> 0 Then
        Application.StatusBar = "Please wait while Excel source is opened ... "
        Set xlApp = CreateObject("Excel.Application")
        bXStarted = True
    End If

    On Error GoTo 0

    ' Open the workbook to input the data
    Set xlWB = xlApp.Workbooks.Open(strPath)
    Set xlSheet = xlWB.Sheets("Sheet1")

    ' Process each selected record
    rCount = xlSheet.UsedRange.Rows.Count
    For Each olItem In Application.ActiveExplorer.Selection
        sText = olItem.Body
        vText = Split(sText, Chr(13))

        ' Find the next empty line of the worksheet
        rCount = rCount + 1

        ' Check each line of text in the message body
        For i = UBound(vText) To 0 Step -1

            If InStr(1, vText(i), "title: ") > 0 Then
                vItem = Split(vText(i), Chr(58))
                xlSheet.Range("A" & rCount) = Trim(vItem(1))
            End If

            If InStr(1, vText(i), "gender: ") > 0 Then
                vItem = Split(vText(i), Chr(58))
                xlSheet.Range("B" & rCount) = Trim(vItem(1))
            End If

            If InStr(1, vText(i), "country: ") > 0 Then
                vItem = Split(vText(i), Chr(58))
                xlSheet.Range("C" & rCount) = Trim(vItem(1))
            End If

            If InStr(1, vText(i), "keyword: ") > 0 Then
                vItem = Split(vText(i), Chr(58))
                xlSheet.Range("E" & rCount) = Trim(vItem(1))
            End If

            If InStr(1, vText(i), "first_name: ") > 0 Then
                vItem = Split(vText(i), Chr(58))
                xlSheet.Range("G" & rCount) = Trim(vItem(1))
            End If

            If InStr(1, vText(i), "phone_number: ") > 0 Then
                vItem = Split(vText(i), Chr(58))
                xlSheet.Range("I" & rCount) = Trim(vItem(1))
            End If

            If InStr(1, vText(i), "username: ") > 0 Then
                vItem = Split(vText(i), Chr(58))
                xlSheet.Range("F" & rCount) = Trim(vItem(1))
            End If

            If InStr(1, vText(i), "upload: ") > 0 Then
                vItem = Split(vText(i), Chr(58))
                xlSheet.Range("O" & rCount) = Trim(vItem(1))
            End If

        Next i
        xlWB.Save

    Next olItem
    xlWB.Close SaveChanges:=True
        
    If bXStarted Then
        xlApp.Quit
    End If

    Set olItem = Nothing
    Set xlSheet = Nothing
    Set xlWB = Nothing
    Set xlApp = Nothing
End Sub
```

The upload field displays " http " not " http://all-free-download.com/free-photos/download/autumns-evening-sun_513398.html  ".

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Chr(58) is Colon

By doing `Split(vText(i), Chr(58))`, you are taking the original string and splitting it by the delimiter colon

eg: File upload: http://all-free-download.com/free-photos/download/autumns-evening-sun_513398.html

vItem(0)= File upload

vItem(1)= http

vItem(2)= //all-free-download.com/free-photos/download/autumns-evening-sun_513398.html

So in order to get the full link that you wanted, you have to concatenate vItem.

eg.  `vItem(1) & ":" & vItem(2)`

Comment: Thanks Keenlearner,                                                                                                    
                                                                                                                       
It works.  :)

Answer (score 0):

i tried your code.  there is an issue with finding the next available cell when the worksheet is blank (the formula *xlSheet.UsedRange.Rows.Count* returns 1 for both, no rows used, and one row used)

here is a rewrite that seems to work correctly

if-then routines have been replaced by case statements

```
Sub CopyToExcel()
    Dim xlApp As Object
    Dim xlWB As Object
    Dim xlSheet As Object

    Dim olItem As Outlook.mailItem
    Dim vText As Variant
    Dim rCount As Long

    Dim vItem As Variant
    Dim i As Long
    Dim bXStarted As Boolean
    Const strPath As String = "E:\Project\Test outlook.xlsx"      ' the path of the workbook


    If Application.ActiveExplorer.Selection.Count = 0 Then
         MsgBox "No Items selected!", vbCritical, "Error"
         Exit Sub
    End If

    On Error Resume Next

    Set xlApp = GetObject(, "Excel.Application")

    If Err <> 0 Then
        Application.StatusBar = "Please wait while Excel source is opened ... "
        Set xlApp = CreateObject("Excel.Application")
        bXStarted = True
    End If

'   xlApp.Visible = True                                          ' show worksheet (for debugging)

    On Error GoTo 0

    Set xlWB = xlApp.Workbooks.Open(strPath)                      ' Open the workbook to input the data
    Set xlSheet = xlWB.Sheets("Sheet1")

'   rCount = xlSheet.UsedRange.Rows.Count                         ' does not work (returns 1 when no data on worksheet)

    Dim formula As String                                         '
    formula = "MATCH(TRUE, INDEX(ISBLANK(A:A), 0, 0), 0)"         ' cell formula: =MATCH(TRUE, INDEX(ISBLANK(A:A), 0, 0), 0)

    rCount = xlApp.Evaluate(formula)                              ' find next empty line on worksheet using a cell formula

    For Each olItem In Application.ActiveExplorer.Selection       ' Process each selected email

        vText = Split(olItem.body, vbCrLf)                        ' convert email body to an array of text lines
        For i = 0 To UBound(vText)                                ' Check each line of text in the message body

            vItem = Split(":" & vText(i), ":", 3)                 ' split line into max 3 parts (leading ":" added to prevent fail on blank lines)

            Select Case LCase(vItem(1))                           ' LCase for case insensitive comparison
                Case "title"
                    xlSheet.Range("A" & rCount) = Trim(vItem(2))
                Case "gender"
                    xlSheet.Range("B" & rCount) = Trim(vItem(2))
                Case "country"
                    xlSheet.Range("C" & rCount) = Trim(vItem(2))
                Case "keyword"
                    xlSheet.Range("E" & rCount) = Trim(vItem(2))
                Case "first name"
                    xlSheet.Range("G" & rCount) = Trim(vItem(2))
                Case "phone number"
                    xlSheet.Range("I" & rCount) = Trim(vItem(2))
                Case "username"
                    xlSheet.Range("F" & rCount) = Trim(vItem(2))
                Case "file upload"
                    xlSheet.Range("O" & rCount) = Trim(vItem(2))
'               Case Else
'                   do something else here
            End Select

        Next i
        xlWB.Save

        rCount = rCount + 1                                       ' point to next empty line of the worksheet

    Next olItem
    Set olItem = Nothing

    xlWB.Close SaveChanges:=True

    If bXStarted Then
        xlApp.Quit
    End If

    Set xlSheet = Nothing
    Set xlWB = Nothing
    Set xlApp = Nothing
End Sub
```

Answer (score -1):

```
If InStr(1, vText(i), "upload: ") > 0 Then
    vItem = Split(vText(i), Chr(58), 2) '<< optional parameter controls how many splits...
    xlSheet.Range("O" & rCount) = Trim(vItem(1))
End If
```

Comment: Please add explanations to your answer. Answering without explanations is useless.

Comment: The comment about the additional parameter covers it: OP wrote the rest of the code themselves, so they should follow what's going on...